# formula to set value from common two columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, copy-paste

[image]

i'm trying to compare **old_id(A)** & **New_id(C)** and based on **old_id(A)** i need to copy **SF_ID(B)** and paste it into **SF_ID(D)** with **New_id(C)**...

is it possible ? if yes then please suggest the formula..

expected Outcome should be in Yellow color (New_Id (C) and SF_Id(D)) based on **A & B**
[image]

Thanks a lot in Advance !!

Comment: So what will the expected outcome be?

Comment: Can you please check the updated question ? hope it should be clear now :)

Comment: OK... Just a sec...

Comment: don't know why but doesn't seems work :(

Comment: You want to compare column A and column C. If they are the same then display then copy the value from B to D?

Comment: Right...exactly !!

Comment: In that case the answer below should work. Sorry.. The formula should be `=IF(A2=C2,B2,"")` I will update my answer.

Comment: Okay !! got it...this is absolutely right but in this scenario A have lots of value (34000) and c have only (286)..i am sure C's value is available in A but where (in 2495 line) that's very time consuming...so, what would you suggest ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128159/discussion-between-nihar-and-andreas).

Comment: look at my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not clear, but in chat it became clear.
You need to use Vlookup to find the values if they are not on the same row.

First select column A and B and name this range, you do that in the white box that is above the A column that usually displays the cell you have selected.
Lets name the range "rng".

Then in column D insert this formula:

```
=vlookup(C2,rng,2,False)
```

It will search for the value C2 in the named range rng, and if it finds the value it will grab the second column value (SF_ID) and display it in column D.
If it does not find it, it will display an error message. You can remove that message if you use this formula instead:

```
=iferror(vlookup(C2,rng,2,False),"")
```